# ajax rendered form will not submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, ajaxform

I have a form that is rendered via ajax when someone clicks on a show form button.  The form renders correctly, but it does not submit.  When I press submit, nothing happens and the server does not receive anything.  Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @employer_profile, :html => { :class => "clearfix", :id => "the_form"}, 
    remote: true do |f| %> 
    <%= f.text_field :position, class: "field" %>
<%= f.submit "SAVE", class: "button button-save button-submit" %>
```

Here is the html that is generated:

```
<form id="the_form" class="clearfix" method="post" data-remote="true" 
 action="/employer_profiles/13" accept-charset="UTF-8"
    <input id="employer_profile_position" class="field" type="text"
     name="employer_profile[position]"></input>
<input class="button button-save button-submit" type="submit" value="SAVE" 
 name="commit"></input>
```

Why is the form not submitting?

Comment: you may show the generated action.

Comment: Nothing is generated.  I just click submit  and nothing happens.

Comment: show the html code and look for `form action="..."`

Comment: is `jquery_ujs.js` includes in you html code? otherwise `remote` isn't workung.

Comment: It is included on the original page that has the button that loads the ajax form.  i tried including it on the form page but that did not make the form work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45671/discussion-between-devanand-and-philip7899)

Comment: did you figure this out??? just ran into the sme issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the submit button to send an AJAX request by adding the `remote: true` parameter to the call?

`<%= f.submit "SAVE", class: "button button-save button-submit", remote: true %>`